# How to generate a PDF from a HTML string on React Native WEB

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pdf, expo, pdf-generation

I am trying to generate a pdf from a HTML on react native when I use web version, but It does not work at all.

I've tried many libraries such as:

- Expo print library (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/print/)
- React Native Libraries (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-html-to-pdf)
- htmltoPdf (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf-html)

If I use **htmltopdf**, my app does not build.

Does anyone has a solution for **Generate a pdf from html on REACT NATIVE for WEB**?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm trying to generate a pdf from html on react-native in Android. However, it only works in web.
I used `expo-print` and followed the following tutorial: https://www.mywebtuts.com/blog/react-native-generate-pdf-file-example

Also in more detail here: https://upplabs.com/blog/how-to-generate-a-pdf-document-in-a-react-native-project/